# JPA query to concat null field

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Hello this is query for concating brand name, title and undertitle

```
@Query(value="SELECT c FROM ProductOption c WHERE  cast( c.id AS string ) like %:search% or CONCAT(COALESCE(c.product.brand.name,''),' ',c.product.title,' ',c.underTitle) like %:search%")
Page<ProductOption> findAllBySearch(String search,Pageable pageable);
```

however everytime brand is null, productoption is not included in response..

Basically what i want is to concat brand name , title and undertitle if brand is not null and if it is null concat by title and undertitle..

I have tried many more ways using CASE etd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you concatenate the strings in your WHERE clause, you use the [path operator "."](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpql/#Path_expressions_or_implicit_joins) to navigate from your `ProductOption` to the `product` and from there to the `brand`.

```
@Query(value="... CONCAT(COALESCE(c.product.brand.name,''),' ',c.product.title,' ',c.underTitle) like %:search%")
```

This creates 2 [INNER JOINs](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-difference-join-left-join-fetch-join) in the generated SQL statement that exclude `ProductOption`s that don't have a `product` or a `product` without a `brand`.

You can avoid that by [defining LEFT JOINs](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpql/#Left_Outer_Joins) in the FROM clause and referencing the alias of these JOINS in the WHERE clause:

```
@Query(value="SELECT c FROM ProductOption c LEFT JOIN c.product p LEFT JOIN p.brand b WHERE  cast( c.id AS string ) like %:search% or CONCAT(COALESCE(b.name,''),' ',p.title,' ',c.underTitle) like %:search%")
Page<ProductOption> findAllBySearch(String search,Pageable pageable);
```